# Dynamically Add/Delete a Button

Tags: android, button, android-studio

Using android studio, I am trying to create an "inventory" activity. The main body of this activity is a scrollview. When I click the "add" button it opens an activity that has fields to enter data about the item. In turn when the item is added I want the app to add a button to the scrollview on the inventory activity.

How do I add a button to a class from a button on a different activity?

When I click the button can I have the scrollview hidden and show the info about the item clicked? or how could I display the information?

Looking ahead, When I click the "delete" button an activity opens listing all the item names and removes an item from the list. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: cross activity communication is cumbersome. To make a list of items that displays the details of an item when clicked, I would rather use Views

Comment: How would I go about using Views? is there a suggested website I could look at?

Comment: Could you clarify by what you mean in terms of an add button? Is the add button within the scroll view?

Comment: On activity 1 there is a scrollview and 2 buttons; an add button and a delete button. The add button opens up to activity 2 with data fields. once those data fields are populated, the user taps the add button on activity 2. This button does 2 things: 1 causes a button to be added into the scrollview in activity 1 and 2 creates a data enrtry so when the button in the scroll view is tapped, the user can view the inventory items data. Each button added has the text of the name of the inventory item added.